# Tensorflow Deep and Wide Demo issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5

I tried to run the code directly from tensorflow's [Deep and Wide demo repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py):

There is an immediate issue with `urllib` which can easily be fixed by using `urllib.request` instead. The code will still not run afterward though, I get the following error:

```
m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/USER/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 182, in fit
monitors=monitors)
File "/Users/USER/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 449, in _train_model
train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
File "/Users/USER/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 156, in _get_train_ops
logits = self._logits(features, is_training=True)
File "/Users/USER/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 294, in _logits
if self._get_linear_feature_columns() and self._get_dnn_feature_columns():
File "/Users/USER/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 216, in _get_dnn_feature_columns
self._dnn_feature_columns)) if self._dnn_feature_columns else None
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < _SparseColumnKeys()
```

I'm having trouble finding the source of this issue. There doesn't seem to be anyone else experiencing this issue. Tensorflow is installed in virtualenv (tensorflow) on python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

urllib is for 2.7, try running it in 2.7 instead of 3.5.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this issue is with urllib, does it? For unknown reasons I've had issues installing tensorflow with python2.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This solved it.

I had to install Tensorflow under Python 2.7. Here's how to do it with a virtual environment, using Conda:

```
# Python 2.7
$ conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7

$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow)$  # Your prompt should change

# Linux/Mac OS X, Python 2.7/3.4/3.5, CPU only:
(tensorflow)$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Check out: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#using-conda